# addEventListener work's but console send a Warning

Tags: javascript

I have no idea why it happens.

I have this script in a .js document which is attached in footer place:

```
var esborrar = document.getElementsByClassName("button-tab");

for (var i =0; i <= esborrar.length; i++) {

   var docs = esborrar[i];
   docs.style.color="black";
}
```

it works fine, but console send this warning:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

any idea?

thanks

Comment: `delete` is a keyword. Don't use it

Comment: delete is a reserved word for JavaScript

Comment: Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) and paste your code there. JSHint will give you clues about what’s wrong with your JS code.

Comment: That's not a warning; it's an error, as the message clearly states. What about this "works fine"??

Comment: yes, this works fine... color's link change to black...

Comment: You simply have a classic off-by-one error; `<=` should be `<`, because `esborrar[esborrar.length]` is guaranteed to be `undefined`.

Comment: @apsillers thanks!! I changed <= to < and console no sends anything!

Answer (score 0):

Your for statement uses <= instead of a <. This means you will end up with a larger number than the array contains, therefore an undefined. :)